# How to output top 10 results from a PageRank Pyspark algorithm?

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, mapreduce

I need to output only the top 10 results from the PageRank algorithm using Pyspark in Hadoop. The original code is available here:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pagerank.py

The code currently outputs all of the map URLs and their ranks into the system using these two lines of code at the very end:

`for (link, rank) in ranks.collect():`

`print("%s has rank: %s." % (link, rank))`

I'd like to be able to output the top 10 results based on the rank. A bonus would be to write it directly to a csv file.

I tried:

`df = []`
`for (link, rank) in ranks.collect():`

`df.append(`
`{`
`'Link': link`
`'Rank': rank`
`}`
`)`

```
df.show(n=10)
```

And also tried:

`combined_df = rank_rdd.zip(link_rdd).toDF(['rank', 'link'])`

`sorted_df = combined_df.sort(asc('rank'))`

`top_10 = sorted_df.limit(10) top_10.show()`

No luck yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with your second approach!

Make a few adjustments. First, sort the ranks in descending order, and then convert the RDD to a DataFrame. Finally, you can write the top 10 results to a CSV file. You can try this:

```
# assuming you have initialized your SparkSession as spark
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PageRank Top 10") \
    .getOrCreate()

# assuming the ranks RDD has been computed
combined_rdd = ranks.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))  # swap the link and rank positions
combined_df = spark.createDataFrame(combined_rdd, ["Rank", "Link"])  # convert the RDD to a DataFrame

sorted_df = combined_df.sort(desc('Rank'))  # aort the DataFrame by rank in descending order
top_10 = sorted_df.limit(10)  # Get the top 10 results
top_10.show()  # Display the top 10 results

# write the top 10 results to a CSV file
top_10.write.csv("top_10_pagerank.csv", mode="overwrite", header=True)
```